# Boost : serialization of class instances that contain pointers

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

If I serialize an instance of the class **Container**, using Boost library:

```
class Container
{
   public:
      Block** blocks;
      int blocksNumber;
}

class Block
{
   public:
     int blockType;
     unsigned char* data;
}
```

And then filling all the necessary data to get a complete Container:

```
Container container = new Container();
container.blocksNumber=5;
Block** blocks = (Block**)malloc(sizeof(Block*)*container.blocksNumber);
blocks[0] = (Block*)malloc(sizeof(Block));
//..... Filling all the necessary data... and constructing the container
```

So my question is: Would the serialized format of the instance **container** contain all the allocated **data**? In other words, if I deserialize the serialized format of container, would I be able to read the content of **data**? Thank you a lot!

Comment: Have you tried it? What (---the hell---) are you using malloc and double pointers for in c++ anyways

Comment: I have the same problem with you, but Boost serialization didn't support double pointer, that is awful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to waste any time contemplating why you bring unsafe C cannons in here. You're looking to use Boost Serialization, a modern generic C++ library.

Here's what it should look like:

```
struct Block {
    int blockType;
    std::vector<uint8_t> data;
};

struct Container {
    std::vector<std::vector<Block>> block_lists;
};
```

See a complete working sample:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d3c6aa4dcf76eca9)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>

class Block
{
   public:
     int blockType;
     std::vector<uint8_t> data;

   private:
       friend class boost::serialization::access;
       template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned) {
               ar & blockType;
               ar & data;
           }
};

class Container
{
   public:
       std::vector<std::vector<Block>> block_lists;

   private:
       friend class boost::serialization::access;
       template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned) {
               ar & block_lists;
           }
};

#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>

int main()
{
    Container const letshavesome = {
        { // block_lists
            {
                Block { 1, { 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14 } },
                Block { 2, { 0x21, 0x22, 0x23, 0x24 } },
                Block { 3, { 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34 } },
            },
            {
                Block { 4, { 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44 } },
                Block { 5, { 0x51, 0x52, 0x53, 0x54 } },
                Block { 6, { 0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x64 } },
            },
        }
    };

    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(std::cout);
    oa << letshavesome;
}
```

Output

> `22 serialization::archive 11 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 1 4 0 17 18 19 20 2 4 0 33 34 35 36 3 4 0 49 50 51 52 3 0 4 4 0 65 66 67 68 5 4 0 81 82 83 84 6 4 0 97 98 99 100`