# Is boost serialization library is userful? Why doesn't it support "pointer to pointer" serialization?

Tags: c++, pointers, serialization, boost

Boost serialization library is powerful, but there are some features that I cannot stand.
For example, Person is a class and I have a crowd of person:

```
int n = 10;
Person **persons = new Person*[n];
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    persons[i] = new Person(...);  // whatever Person is.
}
```

Here,  I wanted to serialize persons, but it didn't work. If I change code like this:

```
Person *persons[10];
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    persons[i] = new Person(...);  // whatever Person is.
}
```

**Now it did work. But in my project, the n is not constant. So I wonder why boost serialization library doesn't support "pointer to pointer" serialization.** In real project, "pointer to pointer" is very common, but boost doesn't support. So, is boost serialization library that userful? I don't think so...

Comment: `In real project, "pointer to pointer" is very common, but boost doesn't support.` It's actually wrong, `std::vector`, `boost::ptr_vector` etc handle this. Calling new/delete manually should be uncommon.

Comment: Yes, boost support STL library, but for a time-critical program, vector/list/set has worse performance than array. The data is large, finding and traversing will be very slow if use STL library...

Comment: `vector` is just dynamic-array, nothing else, I have no idea, how find and traversing can be very slow. You use profiler to figure out this?

Comment: In c++, "pointer to pointer" is **very** uncommon. Also relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27430431/boost-serialization-of-class-instances-that-contain-pointers/27463442#27463442

Comment: This "vector has worse performance than array" business reminds me of [the story Bjarne told](http://youtu.be/4cCeUfzH-No?t=48m44s) at a CppCon panel.

Comment: Thank you, Vectors are arrays under the hood. The performance is almost the same.I misunderstood this.

Answer (score 2):

I think, that you should use containers, but, if profiler says you, that vector is too slow, you can just serialize pointers, I have no idea what is wrong with it. [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html)

So, you can just use (also store size before elements)

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
   ar & persons[i];
}
```

where `ar` is archive.

[Simple live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f889e04993e6a243)

Comment: ＋1 Thanks for debunking. With some Boost Serializationisms that code can still be considerably cleaner :)

Answer (score 2):

Serialize:

```
archive::binary_oarchive oa(ss);
oa << n << boost::serialization::make_array(persons, n);
```

Deserialize:

```
archive::binary_iarchive ia(ss);
size_t loaded_size;
ia >> loaded_size;
Person** loaded = new Person*[loaded_size];
ia >> boost::serialization::make_array(loaded, loaded_size);
```

Test:

```
assert(n == loaded_size);
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    assert(*persons[i] == *loaded[i]);
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/846c8e53ea814ba9)**

```
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace boost;

class Person {
  public:
    Person(int a = 0) : age(a) {}
    bool operator==(const Person &rhs) const { return age == rhs.age; }

  private:
    int age;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <typename Archive> void serialize(Archive &a, unsigned int) { a &age; }
};

Person** make_persons(size_t n) {
    Person **persons = new Person *[n];
    int i = 10;
    std::generate_n(persons, n, [i]{ return new Person(i); });

    return persons;
}

void free_persons(Person** persons, size_t n) {
    std::for_each(persons, persons+n, [](Person*p){ delete p; });
    delete[] persons;
}

int main() {
    const size_t n = 10;
    Person** persons = make_persons(n);

    std::stringstream ss;

    archive::binary_oarchive oa(ss);
    oa << n << serialization::make_array(persons, n);

    archive::binary_iarchive ia(ss);
    size_t loaded_size;
    ia >> loaded_size;
    Person** loaded = new Person*[loaded_size];
    ia >> serialization::make_array(loaded, loaded_size);

    assert(n == loaded_size);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        assert(*persons[i] == *loaded[i]);

    free_persons(loaded, n);
    free_persons(persons, n);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The C++ Standard doesn't provide a way for the boost library (or any other code) to know the size of "`T` array" a pointer-to-`T` points at.  That's why - for example - `main()` has `argc`.  Consequently, it can't work without some help from you.  That's why you're better off using Standard containers.  Your objections regarding performance sound like FUD to me... there are one or two small performance issues (more so with C++03) - but I doubt you've ever encountered them, especially not in any code where it mattered....